# How does がかえ connect this sentence together?

Tags: translation

Please consider the sentence highlighted in bold (other text is given for context):

> 俺、さっきまでゲームして寝てたはずで、**親丸がかえの高校生だった**んだぞ。

I know that 親丸 means *"parents circle"* and 高校生だったんだぞ means *"was a high school student"*, but how does がかえ transition or connect this sentence together? が　かえ can be inferred as *"went"* but I don't understand how this is actually connecting.

Comment: A bit more context will help. Maybe a few more sentences before and after this?

Comment: the actual text was 俺、さっきまでゲームして寝てたはずで、親丸がかえの高校生だったんだぞ。

Comment: I edited your question a bit to improve formatting, and also made the title more specific.

Answer (score 1):

> 親丸がかえの高校生だったんだぞ。

It is 親が**丸{まる}抱｛がか｝え**の高校生だった。

According to the definition of 丸抱え [here](http://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%B8%E6%8A%B1%E3%81%88), it is:

> Noun
>   1. completely financed; sponsored; under patronage​

The given sentence means *I was a high school student completely financed by my parents*.